# create dictionary using nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I am looking to create a dictionary from nested loops, that iterate through dates and variables. I would like to create this as efficiently as possible given the length of my dates is ~ 400 and myvars ~ 50,000. many thanks.

```
fmap = dict.fromkeys(range(len(dates)*len(myvars)))
count = 0
for j in dates:
    for i in myvars:
        fmap[count] = partial(dosomething, i, j)
        count = count+1
```

Comment: What is the point of calling `dict.fromkeys()`?  The nested loop will reassign all the keys anyway.

Comment: I recommend using a dict comprehension equivalent to your nested loops.  Even better, you can save time if you parameterize your `partial` function to build the entire dict in one call.

Comment: Assuming you really need to call `partial()` two million times and store each result to a key in a dict, I don't see any way to make this code more efficient.  I suspect the only real efficiency gains will be in coming up with a way to avoid making two million calls to `partial()`, but you haven't given us enough detail to speculate on how that might be done.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and what the final dictionary should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, it should be quite efficient:

```
count = len(dates) * len(myvars)
fmap = dict(zip(range(count), [partial(dosomething, i, j) for j in dates for i in myvars]))
```

Comment: How is this more efficient?  It's _less code_, but I'm not sure that's what the questioner meant.

Comment: Using list comprehension is <s>surely</s> often more efficient then for loops.

Comment: I'll take your word for it.

Comment: And also is doing useless calculation, like incrementing `count` each loop. My code is surely more efficient, but I don't know if it is the best solution.